# Android studio debugging stops working (OSx / Samsung Galaxy S5)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

After successfully launching or debugging an app, subsequent debugging sessions fail. Logcat shows a "connection refused" message.

Unplugging and plugging in the cable is a workaround but a list of dead devices builds up in the Devices view[image: dead devices]

I also sometimes see an "adb not responding dialog" [image: adb not responding]

Environment:

- Android Studio Build: 0.5.8, AI-135.1155795, 20140506
- Android SDK Tools 22.6.3
- Android SDK Platform-tools 19.1
- OS X 10.9.2

This problem also affected older version of AS.

Comment: I get that too sometimes.  However, the unplug/plug routine does not result in the old listings being retained.  I'm on Android Studio 0.8.2.  It might be a bug on your version of Android Studio.

Comment: Same bug for me on Android Studio 0.8.9. There is an issue opened here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65301

Answer (score 0):

I am using XUbuntu and have the same issue, what fixes it for me is clicking on the 
"Android Device Monitor", then stopping the unresponsive app and rerunning the app back in Android Studio. This seems to restart adb correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If your adb stops responding there is an easy way to reset adb. You need to go to the folder where your android sdk is install, find the location of "adb" and once you are in the folder you can issue the following command.

adb kill-server
adb start-server

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade Android Studio version, that is fixed on the newest android studio version 1.1

Comment: I have 0.8.9 version and bug is still happening